# Software that fills out a simple online form for me once a day?

Tags: automation, forms, autocomplete

I am looking for something that would give me ability to program it so it will fill out a simple form multiple times every day using things like name and email and password. I know they have applications like this for games like auto-clicker and others like it but not sure if they have one for this specific use or if there is some way I can hard code it myself? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request may be resolved with a couple of different types of programs. One program that I use is called [MacroExpress](https://www.macroexpress.com/). It has a very flexible and powerful scripting feature which allows one to use time-of-day, mouse location, keyboard outputs and many other entries. You may also find other macro/mouse/keyboard recording software that will serve your purpose.

Another type of program that may work is a password manager. I use [Roboform](https://www.roboform.com/), which allows me to enter email address, password and other form data to be entered with the click of a mouse.

There are also other password managers but I don't know that they will also handle form filling.

Comment: I'll definitely check out MacroExpress I think that's exactly what i'm looking for! I'll get back to you if it works...